# Authenticate to SharePoint REST API from external service

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-rest-api

I am trying to figure out how to authenticate calls to our on premises SharePoint 2013 REST API. So far, I've come across a lot of blogs that show you how to do it for SharePoint online. Here's one for example:

http://paulryan.com.au/2014/spo-remote-authentication-rest/#comment-14866

This blog says that you need to POST a message to https://login.microsoft.com STS service. For on-prem, I assume we just change that to the local STS endpoint? I'm struggling to find any documentation that outlines the steps needed to request an request token from a local STS service. To be honest, I'm not even sure I have the right approach.

To add some context, the remote service that will be trying to update a SharePoint list is an Oracle product. It is on the same domain and is not behind a firewall. Our SharePoint instance is configured for claims authentication. Users can authenticate with Windows credentials or a 3rd party SAML provider (sitting behind ADFS).

So far, I was able to construct the calls for /_api/contextinfo and the list itself:

```
url:"https://sharepoint.listurl.com/_api/contextinfo",
headers: {
    "accept":"application/json;odata=verbose",
    "content-type":"application/json;odata=verbose"
},
type:"POST",
success:function(data) {console.log(data)}

    url:"https://sharepoint.listurl.com/_api/lists/GetByTitle('Title')/Items(ID)",
    type: "POST",
    data:{'__metadata': { 'type': 'entityTypeName' }, 'field1':'field1 value'},
    contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
    headers: {
       "Accept":"application/json;odata=verbose",
       "X-RequestDigest":digest,
       "X-HTTP-Method":"MERGE",
       "If-Match":"*"
    },
```

And that works in the browser. I just need to figure out how to authenticate from a remote source. Any pointers or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you use Javascript? Will your script run into a browser or on server side (like using Node)?

Comment: I just realized it's a 1-year old post... Not sure why the Tweet bot posted it. It would have been interesting that you post what you found to help the community..